# how to play audioplayer in ios using AVAudioplayer

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to create AVAudioPlayer Programatically.I Have small issue if i play audioplayer.
I am displaying 12 audio items in UITableview.If i click first item that corresponding song will play.I should not click any pass button.i click back button and click second item.if i click second item the audio view controller will display.I click play button the song display.In  first song and second song play simultaneously.This is my issue.Please help me anybody.

`-(void)playOrPauseButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
if(playing==NO)

{

[playButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Pause.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

// Here Pause.png is a image showing Pause Button.

NSError *err=nil; 
AVAudioSession *audioSession=[AVAudioSession sharedInstance];

[audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];

NSLog(@"%@ %d",urlsArray,selectedIndex);

NSString *sourcePath=[urlsArray objectAtIndex:selectedIndex];

NSData *objectData=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:sourcePath]];

audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:objectData error:&err];

audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = 0;

[audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
audioPlayer.delegate=self;
[audioPlayer play];
playing=YES;
}
else if (playing==YES)

{
[playButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"play.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[audioPlayer pause];

playing=NO;

}
if (self.audioPlayer)

{
[self updateViewForPlayerInfo];

[self updateViewForPlayerState];

[self.audioPlayer setDelegate:self];

}
}`

-(void)updateViewForPlayerInfo

{

self.songDuration.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d:%02d", (int)self.audioPlayer.duration / 60, (int)self.audioPlayer.duration % 60, nil];

NSLog(@"%f", self.audioPlayer.duration);

self.progressBar.maximumValue = self.audioPlayer.duration;

self.volumeSlider.value = self.audioPlayer.volume;

}

-(void)updateViewForPlayerState

{

[self updateCurrentTime];

if (self.updatedTimer)

{

[self.updatedTimer invalidate];

}

if (self.audioPlayer.playing)

{

self.updatedTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01 target:self selector:@selector(updateCurrentTime) userInfo:self.audioPlayer repeats:YES];

}

}

-(void)updateCurrentTime

{

//NSLog(@"self.audioPlayer.currentTime = %f", self.audioPlayer.currentTime);

self.currentTime.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d:%02d", (int)self.audioPlayer.currentTime / 60, (int)self.audioPlayer.currentTime % 60, nil];

self.progressBar.value = self.audioPlayer.currentTime;

}

-(void)volumeSliderMoved:(UISlider *)sender

{

self.audioPlayer.volume=[sender value];

}

Comment: help me anybody plz.Yesterday onwards i struck this issue

Answer (score 0):

Stop the player when you go back. Maybe in ViewWillDisappear or before you create a new instance of audioplayer, you can call

```
if(self.audioplayer) {
  [self.audioPlayer stop];
  self.audioPlayer = nil;
}
```

Comment: @bro thanks for your response.But if i click back button the audioplayer automatically stop.But according to AVAudioplayer if we click back button the audioplayer should not stop na

Comment: yea, you can try deallocating it , so that the instance won't be there anymore. i have edited my comment above.

Answer (score 0):

before creating a new instance of AVAudioPlayer, deallocate or nil the existing instance of player by using following lines

```
sourcePath=Nil;
[audioPlayer stop];
audioPlayer = Nil;
```

Comment: thanks for your response brother.But if i click back button the audioplayer automatically stop.But according to AVAudioplayer if we click back button the audioplayer should not stop na

Comment: @back button is nothing but in navigation bar having back button.If i click back button the Audioviewcontroller should navigate AudioTableviewController.

Comment: this is where you are going wrong, when you click on back button, it pop ups the current class from navigation controller stack to presenting class, and class having audio player goes out of scope, means removed from navigation controller stack. that is why you are facing this unexpected behaviour from audio player class

Comment: i can't understand your post.please explain me briefly

Comment: what happened when we click on back button on navigation bar?

Answer (score 0):

Before initializing the `AVAudioPlayer` remove all the instances that are running before.

```
//YOUR STUFF


NSString *sourcePath=[urlsArray objectAtIndex:selectedIndex];

NSData *objectData=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:sourcePath]];

for (AVAudioPlayer *a in urlsArray) 
    [a stop];

audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:objectData error:&err];

audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = 0;

//REST STUFF
```